# Как вызвать все методы и одного класса с одинаковыми аргументами?

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть класс с несколькими функциями

```php
Class A
{
function aa(arg1, arg2)
  {
  // код;
  }
function ab(arg1, arg2)
  {
  // код;
  }
function ac(arg1, arg2)
  {
  // код;
  }
}
```

Я вызываю так

```php
A::aa(arg1,arg2);
A::ab(arg1,arg2);
A::ab(arg1,arg2);
```

Аргументы у этих функций одинаковые, вызываются из одного класса. Можно ли вызвать их все сразу как-нибудь за "одну строчку кода"? Или, возможно, циклом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать функцию, которая вызывает эти три метода

```
function aaabac(arg1, arg2)
{
    aa(arg1, arg2);
    ab(arg1, arg2);
    ac(arg1, arg2);  
}
```

и вызывать её потом:

```
A::aaabac(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Это, конечно, не упрощает код, но спасибо